# Flink application is running/alive always，but the job is gone

Tags: apache-flink

I am using the detach and yarn-cluster mode to run the flink application in job mode as follows:

```
flink run -d -m yarn-cluster  -yn 10 -ys 1 -yqu QueueA -c com.me.MyFlinkApplicaiton
```

The application starts up and the job in this application starts to consume message from Kafka successuflly.
After running smoothly for serverl hours, the flink yarn application is alive/running, but the job in this application disappears(there is no job/task running any more), all the slots are freed.

My application is a simple `read from Kafka source -> sink to mongodb` application, and I have try/catch the whole sink function's `invoke` method, so there will no exception throws in sink function.

I didn't find usefull log to investigate this problem ,so I would ask what may happen that may cause this behavior

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks I have found out the problem, I have specified the restart strategy in the code as

```
  env.setRestartStrategy(RestartStrategies.noRestart())
```

When the tm exits and jm is cancelled, flink will not try to restart the jm and tm.